# Give an Alias to a column I've casted as a date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Basically I'm selecting all the rows from a table and stripping the time portion of the date using

```
CAST(CREATE_DATE AS DATE)
```

but my results give me the rows I need but the column is unnamed.

How do I give the column a name?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Did you really think it would be faster to type in so many words, submit and wait for the answer than to search the Internet for something like [sql server column alias](http://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+column+alias)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
Cast(create_date as date) as [Column Name Here]
```

You can omit the `[]` if you are not using spaces or reserved words in your column name (which is good practice anyway).